# Dynamically changing the argument of the Retrofit2 interface

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

There is a method for changing the service:

```
@Multipart
@PUT("/api/edit/service/{service_id}/{master_id}")
Observable<SimpleBody> editService(@Path("service_id") String serviceId,
                                   @Path("master_id") String userId,
                                   @Part MultipartBody.Part avatar,
                                   @Part("title") RequestBody title,
                                   @Part("price") RequestBody price,
                                   @Part("description") RequestBody description,
                                   @Part("period") RequestBody periodInMinutes,
                                   @Part("service_category") RequestBody serviceCategory)
```

in which I must send the field that changed, or all the fields, including the changed field. That is, in the above written method, I send all the fields.

But I want to send only that field that has changed, like so:

```
Observable<SimpleBody> editService(@Path("service_id") String serviceId,
                                   @Path("master_id") String userId,
                                   @Part("title") RequestBody title)
```

Only in this case I send the changed `Title`, since I wrote `@Part ("title")` in the `@Part` annotation. So I have to create a separate method for each changed field. I think this is not right.

So, is it possible to send all the changed fields with one argument, and in the `editService()` method, type the following:

```
Observable<SimpleBody> editService(@Path("service_id") String serviceId,
                                   @Path("master_id") String userId,
                                   @Part RequestBody service)
```

Can there is a decision how to group fields in one?

Comment: Have you consider using ``@PartMap``? Could be an option I think. Here's the link: https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/PartMap.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this with `@PartMap`. In my `RetrofitServiceApi`:

```
@Multipart
@PUT("/api/edit/service/{service_id}/{master_id}")
Observable<SimpleBody> editService(@Path("service_id") String serviceId,
                                   @Path("master_id") String userId,
                                   @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> params);
```

And I send this way:

```
String image = serviceModel.getImage();
String title = serviceModel.getTitle();
String description = serviceModel.getDescription();
String period = serviceModel.getPeriod();
int price = serviceModel.getPrice();

if (!tmpServiceClick.getImage().equals(image)) {
     parameters.putAll(RetrofitRequestUtil.fileToRequestBodyMap(file, "avatar"));
}
if (!tmpServiceClick.getTitle().equals(title)) {
     parameters.put("title", RetrofitRequestUtil.toRequestBody(title));
}
if (!tmpServiceClick.getDescription().equals(description)) {
     parameters.put("description", RetrofitRequestUtil.toRequestBody(description));
}
if (!tmpServiceClick.getPeriod().equals(period)) {
     parameters.put("period", RetrofitRequestUtil.toRequestBody(period));
}
if (tmpServiceClick.getPrice() != price) {
    parameters.put("price", RetrofitRequestUtil.toRequestBody(String.valueOf(price)));
}

retrofitInterface.editService(masterId, serviceModel.getPublicId(), parameters));
```

RetrofitRequestUtil.class:

```
public static RequestBody toRequestBody(String value) {
    return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), value);
}
```